# SQL query, how to improve?

Tags: mysql, sql

I did a task to write an SQL query and I wonder if I can improve it somehow.

**Description:**

Let's say we have a db on some [online service](https://sqliteonline.com/)

**Let's create tables, and insert some data**

```
create table players (
    player_id integer not null unique,
    group_id integer not null
);

create table matches (
    match_id integer not null unique,
    first_player integer not null,
    second_player integer not null,
    first_score integer not null,
    second_score integer not null
);

insert into players values(20, 2);
insert into players values(30, 1);
insert into players values(40, 3);
insert into players values(45, 1);
insert into players values(50, 2);
insert into players values(65, 1);
insert into matches values(1, 30, 45, 10, 12);
insert into matches values(2, 20, 50, 5, 5);
insert into matches values(13, 65, 45, 10, 10);
insert into matches values(5, 30, 65, 3, 15);
insert into matches values(42, 45, 65, 8, 4);
```

**The output of the query should be:**

```
group_id | winner_id
--------------------
1        | 45
2        | 20
3        | 40
```

So, we should output the winner (player id) of each group. Winner is the player, who got max amount of points in matches.

If user is alone in the group - he's a winner automatically, in case players have equal amount of points - the winner is the one, who has lower id value.

Output should be ordered by group_id field

**My solution:**

```
SELECT 
  results.group_id, 
  results.winner_id 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      summed.group_id, 
      summed.player_id AS winner_id, 
      MAX(summed.sum) AS total_score 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          mapped.player_id, 
          mapped.group_id, 
          SUM(mapped.points) AS sum 
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              p.player_id, 
              p.group_id, 
              CASE WHEN p.player_id = m.first_player THEN m.first_score WHEN p.player_id = m.second_player THEN m.second_score ELSE 0 END AS points 
            FROM 
              players AS p 
              LEFT JOIN matches AS m ON p.player_id = m.first_player 
              OR p.player_id = m.second_player
          ) AS mapped 
        GROUP BY 
          mapped.player_id
      ) as summed 
    GROUP BY 
      summed.group_id 
    ORDER BY 
      summed.group_id
  ) AS results;
```

It works, but I'm 99% sure it can be cleaner. Will be thankful for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `UNION ALL` to extract from `matches` 2 columns: `player_id` and `score` for all players and their scores.
Then aggregate to get each player's total score.
Finally do a `LEFT` join of `players` to the resultset you obtained, use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect all players of each group in descending order respective to their total score and with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` pick the 1st player:

```
SELECT p.group_id, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p.player_id ORDER BY t.score DESC, p.player_id), ',', 1) winner_id
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
  FROM (
    SELECT first_player player_id, first_score score FROM matches
    UNION ALL
    SELECT second_player, second_score FROM matches
  ) t  
  GROUP BY player_id
) t ON t.player_id = p.player_id  
GROUP BY p.group_id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/upY2Upe4yzNdYsvamFkmds/0).

Note that, by doing a `LEFT` join, you get in the results all groups, even the ones that do not have any players that participated in any match (just like your sample data), in which case the winner is an arbitrary player (just like your expected results).

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the matches table and sum the points per player (which is I think what you want):

```
select p.player_id, p.group_id, sum(score) as sum_score
from ((select first_player as player_id, first_score as score
       from matches
      ) union all
      (select second_player as player_id, second_score as score
       from matches
      )
     ) mp
     players p
     using (player_id)
group by p.player_id, p.group_id;
```

Next, you can introduce a window function to get the top:

```
select player_id, group_id, sum_score
from (select p.player_id, p.group_id, sum(score) as sum_score,
             row_number() over (partition by p.group_id order by sum(score) desc p.player_id asc) as seqnum
      from ((select first_player as player_id, first_score as score
             from matches
            ) union all
            (select second_player as player_id, second_score as score
             from matches
            )
           ) mp
           players p
           using (player_id)
      group by p.player_id, p.group_id
     ) pg
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you actually want the maximum score over all the matches rather than the `sum()`, then use `max()` instead of `sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
WITH match_records AS (
   SELECT match_id,first_player players, first_score scores FROM matches UNION ALL
    SELECT match_id,second_player, second_score FROM matches 
  )
SELECT group_id, player_id
   FROM
      (SELECT group_id, player_id, players, SUM(scores) ts, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY SUM(scores) DESC) pos
        FROM players p LEFT JOIN match_records mr ON mr.players=p.player_id
GROUP BY group_id, player_id, players) fp
WHERE pos=1 
ORDER BY group_id;
```

It's basically the same idea as others (to un-pivot the `matches` table) but with a slightly different operation.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7c4c9c345a65dc5c0fbf6a5ce620c31)